# why is datasnap http much slower than tcp/ip

Tags: client-server, performance-testing, delphi-xe5, datasnap

Hello i have written a client server application to stream a file from the server to the client. The code is pretty basic in my test:

Server code (it is an executable running as a service or application)

```
function TServerMethods1.DownloadFile(sFile:String; out iOut:Int64): TStream;
begin
  iOut := -1;
  result := TFileStream.Create(sFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  iOut := result.Size;
  TFileStream(Result).Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
end;
```

Client code

```
procedure TForm1.DownloadFileStabiel(sSourceFile,sTargetFile:String);
var
    RetStream: TStream;
    fs:TFileStream;
    oServerMethodsClient:TServerMethods1Client;
    iOut:Int64;
begin
  ClientModule1.SQLConnection1.Connected:=True;
  oServerMethodsClient := nil;

  try
    try
      oServerMethodsClient := TServerMethods1Client.Create(ClientModule1.SQLConnection1.DBXConnection, True);
      RetStream := oServerMethodsClient.DownloadFile(sSourceFile,iOut);

      fs := TFileStream.Create(sTargetFile, fmCreate);

      fs.CopyFrom(retstream,iOut);

      showmessage('Klaar');

    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        showmessage('Oeps download: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    end;

  finally

    ClientModule1.SQLConnection1.Connected:=False;

    FreeAndNIl(fs);
    FreeAndNil(oServerMethodsClient);
  end;
end;
```

In the real application i do things a little different, i implemented file chunks and a progress bar etc. For the problem with the speed it makes no difference.

On the client i use a TSQLConnection, and on the server is use a TDSTCPServerTransport and a TDSHTTPService

When i stream the file using http it is never faster than 1Mb/s and when i stream using tcp/ip it is as fast as the server can handle it's i/o approximately 30a50 Mb/s

I tried different servers and i always see the same speed difference factor. I tried different operating systems, windows server 2003, 2008, 2012, windows 7. Also it makes nog difference running the client and server on the same machine or on different machines.

Can you help me? I was planning on using https, but now i am stuck at tcp/ip

Answer (score 0):

Although datasnap is not famous for it's speed, I think in this case it is not fair to compare transfer over TCP/IP with transfer over HTTP. HTTP has a lot of overhead and has to do file-encoding / decoding.

To check if the bottleneck is DataSnap try to do a transfer with a plain HTTP server (Indy) and compare that speed with the speed that you get with Datasnap.

Answer (score 0):

i just tried with a plain indy server executable and client executable, with indy it is very fast.... Now i am frustrated about Datasnap. It is such a big difference!!

server:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  aResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create('D:\Software\NKDataSnap\voerexpert.zip', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
end;
```

client:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var strm:TFileStream;
begin
  strm := TFileStream.Create('c:\temp\temp.zip',fmCreate);
  IdHTTP1.Get('http://myserver',strm);
  strm.Free;
end;
```